# How do i hide request API URL on browser debugging tool at network tab while ajax call?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, api

I want to send a secure request to the targeted API endpoint and don't want to let the browser to track the requested API URL in browser debugging tool.
Is there any way to decode the API requested URL so that the URL will not be shown in the browser debugger network tab?

I am using pyton django framework.

**Ajax**

```
function Approve(camp_id, updated)
{
    if (updated === 1){
    var payload = {'campaign_status': 5}
    }
    else{
    var payload = {'campaign_status': 1}
    const  token = '{{csrf_token}}';
    }
    $.ajax(
        {
          url: `https://api.example.com`,
            
            data:{
                camp_id:camp_id
            }
            type:"PUT",
              headers:{"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": token },
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),

            success: function(response, xhr)
            {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(response, xhr)
            {
                console.log(response)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have solved this problem by handling my api call via django view, rather than with ajax, final code will look like

**Ajax:**

```
function Approve(camp_id, updated)
{
    if (updated === 1){
    var payload = {'campaign_status': 5}
    }
    else{
    var payload = {'campaign_status': 1}
    const  token = '{{csrf_token}}';
    }
    $.ajax(
        {
          url: `approve/edit`,// django view url
            
            data:{
                camp_id:camp_id
            }
            type:"PUT",
              headers:{"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": token },
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),

            success: function(response, xhr)
            {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(response, xhr)
            {
                console.log(response)
            }
        }
    );
}
```